# How to impose order on fixtures in pytest?

Tags: python, dependencies, pytest, pytest-dependency

I am trying to use [pytest-dependency](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) to make *fixtures* happen in order, regardless of how they are named, and regardless of the order in which they appear in a test's argument list.

The reason I need this, is to create fixtures that require initializations, that depend on other fixtures that require initializations, and they must happen in order. I have quite a few of these, and I don't want to rely on naming or on order in the argument list.

I also don't want to use `pytest_sessionstart`, because it can't take fixture inputs, which causes very unclean code.

---

The trivial example in [the doc](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) shows how to create programmed dependencies for tests:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.dependency()
@pytest.mark.xfail(reason="deliberate fail")
def test_a():
    assert False

@pytest.mark.dependency()
def test_b():
    pass

@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["test_a"])
def test_c():
    pass

@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["test_b"])
def test_d():
    pass

@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["test_b", "test_c"])
def test_e():
    pass
```

This works with output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 5 items

test_sanity.py::test_z XFAIL (deliberate fail)                           [ 20%]
@pytest.mark.dependency()
    @pytest.mark.xfail(reason="deliberate fail")
    def test_z():
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_sanity.py:6: AssertionError

test_sanity.py::test_x PASSED                                            [ 40%]
test_sanity.py::test_c SKIPPED (test_c depends on test_z)                [ 60%]
Skipped: test_c depends on test_z

test_sanity.py::test_d PASSED                                            [ 80%]
test_sanity.py::test_w SKIPPED (test_w depends on test_c)                [100%]
Skipped: test_w depends on test_c


=================== 2 passed, 2 skipped, 1 xfailed in 0.05s ===================
```

---

### Now I want to do the same for fixtures.

My attempt:

`conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

pytest_plugins = ["dependency"]


@pytest.mark.dependency()
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def zzzshould_happen_first():
    assert False


@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["zzzshould_happen_first"])
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def should_happen_last():
    assert False
```

and `test_sanity.py`:

```
def test_nothing():
    assert True
```

Outputs

```
test_sanity.py::test_nothing ERROR                                       [100%]
test setup failed
@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["zzzshould_happen_first"])
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def should_happen_last():
>       assert False
E       assert False

conftest.py:15: AssertionError
```

I expected the error on `zzzshould_happen_first`.

---

Is there a way to impose ordering on fixtures, such that

1. Their name is ignored
2. Their order in the argument list is ignored
3. Other pytest features such as `autouse` can still be applied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a fixture as a dependency directly with pytest. Something like this:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def zzzshould_happen_first():
    assert False


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def should_happen_last(zzzshould_happen_first):
    assert False


def test_nothing():
    assert True
```

It gives what you want:

```
test setup failed
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def zzzshould_happen_first():
>       assert False
E       assert False

answer.py:7: AssertionError
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the trivial solution! I am sorry I have to add a detail now that didn't occur to me: I am using [a plugin](https://github.com/pytest-docker-compose/pytest-docker-compose#:~:text=This%20package%20contains%20a%20pytest,down%20after%20each%20test%20ends.) that adds its own fixtures. They require external initialization, but I can't change them. I am aware that it is an entirely different question, but maybe you have an idea? I want to force my own fixture to run before any other fixture, then I will be able to use this proposed method.

Comment: Ideally, you should be able to give a function to the fixture that would be called before. But maybe your use case doesn't need to change anything to the plugin. I think you should ask the question with some details about what you try to achieve (mainly why you need to do something before loading the docker-compose).

Comment: What I need before docker-compose up is... docker-compose down (and network remove, and network create). The library doesn't clean up in case the environment is not clean to begin with, so I have to do that before it comes into play.

Comment: In this case, I think you should fork the initial project (or open an issue) in order to add your functionality.